# Get localStorage from within extension without loading a page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I know how to get the `localStorage` from any open wep page by using content scripts. So I'm basically able to open a new tab with my own web page and read the storage data with a content script and message it to the background page.

But now I'd like to do this without loading an external page every time. Is there a way to access the `localStorage` of a page directly from within the extension? Maybe some query to chrome directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see [any API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) for that.

Your options are:

- Make a [native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) host application that would read database files directly from `Local Storage` directory in the browser user profile. An example: [What's the best way to read Sqlite3 directly in Browser using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23879087/3959875)
- Put the other page into an iframe: [Is it possible to use HTML5 local storage to share data between pages from different sites?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16146420/3959875)

P.S. "Ironic side note" quoted from [Cross-domain localStorage](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/07/learning-from-xauth-cross-domain-localstorage/) article by Nicholas C. Zakas.

> Who knew cross-domain client-side data storage would be useful? Actually, the WHAT-WG did. In the first draft of the Web Storage specification (at that time, part of HTML5), there was an object called `globalStorage` that allowed you to specify which domains could access certain data. [...]
>   The globalStorage interface was implemented in Firefox 2 prematurely as the specification was still evolving. Due to security concerns, globalStorage was removed from the spec and replaced with the origin-specific localStorage.