# Can a browser extension access a locally-scoped variable in my script?

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extension, cross-browser, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I noticed that browser extensions have the permission to access localStorage from any webpage ([Get localStorage from within extension without loading a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550243/get-localstorage-from-within-extension-without-loading-a-page)) as well as cookies ([Access cookies from Google Chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439377/access-cookies-from-google-chrome-extension)).  If you give them permissions to `access all data on any webpage`, then their glorified window objects can do this. (can browser extensions do more than that?)

Let's assume you have a script like this:

```
<script>
   function SecretThing(){ 
      // give the client a secret safe from browser extensions: (?)
      var mySecret = Crypto.random()
      // some cryptography with mySecret
   } 
   var secretThing = new SecretThing();     
</script>
```

Basically, I am wondering if I could do math on `mySecret` without ever revealing `mySecret` to a chrome extension. inside of a "SecretThing" object. I would only write getters to get stuff (e.g. signed or encrypted messages) from the secret.

I am not sure a window object could even access `mySecret` (or can it?), which is why I think that maybe a browser extension (which i said was mainly a window object) might also not be able to. What do you think? I have never made a browser extension before.

Comment: `secretThing` variable is *globally* scoped so it can be accessed by an extension (in Chrome it's done by injecting a script element with the extractor code, in Firefox it's done via wrappedJSObject) - in other words you need to hide all your stuff in closures and never expose any global variables.

Comment: mySecret is inside secretThing? So mySecret is locally scoped?

Comment: `mySecret` is a local variable inside `SecretThing` function, not `secretThing` object, which doesn't have any accessible properties. You may want to read about closures in JS.